# virtual box strectch to fit resolution

Tags: linux, ubuntu, virtualbox

Hey guys I have a really annoying problem, that I hope someone has figured out. I just installed ubuntu on virtual box and installed the guest additions so everything was great. I had a resolution that stretched across my screen from left to right and the only virtual box components that were visible were the windows vista title bar : minimize/exit/maximize buttons and virtual box controls at the bottom. Now all of a sudden now that I have installed the ubuntu 170mb of automatic updates, I see vertical and horizontal scroll bars that are part of virtual box and the ubuntu resolution will not stretch across my screen anymore.

**What I want is a ubuntu resolution that will stretch to fit the maximized window of virtual box, and remove the scroll bars.**

If anyone has any ideas, I would really appreciate it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Reinstall the guest additions and see what happens.  Anytime the kernel is updated, the guest additions need to be reinstalled.  Occasionally, a kernel update will come out that the guest additions don't work right with, and then you have to wait and try another kernel and/or update to Virtual Box.

Comment: thanks a lot brian you were absolutely right. Thanks again.